# how to display the values entered by a user in form in a servlet program on tomcat?

Tags: html, servlets

I am running a example of form in which i have three fields 'name', 'email', 'pass'.
Now i want to display the values which are entered by the user, along with the message "You are successfully registered".
I'm using tomcat 8.5, JDK 1.8 and SQL Community 5.6

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="register">
        Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
        Email ID:<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
        Password:<input type="text" name="pass" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="register" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Register.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        try{

        //loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //creating connection with the database 
          Connection  conn=DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb","root","root");

        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement
                  ("insert into Student values(?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, email);
        ps.setString(3, pass);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();

          if(i>0)
          {
            out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
          }
          String query = "SELECT * FROM student";

      // create the java statement
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();

      // execute the query, and get a java resultset
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

      // iterate through the java resultset
      while (rs.next())
      {
                    rs.getString("name");
                    rs.getString("email");
                    rs.getString("pass");


        // print the results
        System.out.format("%s, %s, %s\n", name, email, pass);
         System.out.print("name: " + name);
         System.out.print(", email: " + email);
         System.out.print(", pass: " + pass);

      }

      st.close();

        }
        catch(Exception se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
  }
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app  version="3.0" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Register</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Now What code should i add in order to display the user entered values on the screen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all ,Because of you used Servlet, you need to use JSP instead of html;

---

and then, you should make sure your form action's path;

```
<form action="${ pageContext.request.contextPath }/register" method="post">
```

> if you don't use EL Expression,try to use the following one

```
 <form action="/register" method="post">
```

---

java:

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
System.out.print("name: " + name);
System.out.print(", email: " + email);
System.out.print(", pass: " + pass);
```

---

Lastly,you'd better use the MVC later.

Comment: what code i need to write in JSP and where to put <form action="/register" method="post"> plz explain ?

Comment: All of the things that your code write on HTML need to put on the JSP,and <form action="/register" method="post"> put on the <body>

Comment: if you use EL Expression,you should put the <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> on the top of your JSP,and than you can use <form action="${ pageContext.request.contextPath }/register" method="post"> to instead

Comment: If you use the latter one, I can make sure your path is right

Comment: No, i'm not using EL expression. i did simply put all the content of HTML file into JSP with above form action. Now next?

Comment: Pay attention to add on the top of JSP like this :<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

Comment: And then, as my answer says.add some code in you java servlet to let you see the return value

Comment: Remember to run the entire project on TOMCAT rather than just a single JSP.

Comment: <%@page language="java" import="java.util.*" encoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core";prefix="c"%>
I have add these two lines on the top of JSP page. Is it ok?

Comment: oops, sorry ,if you use EL expression, you must add these,bu you don't want to use it so you can Ignore these code unless you encounter 404 errors.But it doesn't go wrong normally.

Comment: where to add above java servlet code in my code?

Comment: just add these code  before try-catch block to make sure values output in the console.This can display information even if your database connection goes wrong.

Comment: I have some confusions like where else i have to make change according to JSP page, In my main servlet page.